# resultados de mysql_query php usarlo en otra consulta mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy tratando de hacer 2 consultas en PHP ...

basicamente seria esta la primera:

```
$sql = \mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblaccounts WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-12-25 0:00:00' AND '2016-07-20 23:59:00'");
```

los resultados de esta consulta necesito poder usarlos para generar los datos de otra consulta ... ejemplo:

```
 while($r2 =  mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceid = '$RESULTADO_DE_LA_PRIMERA_CONSULTA'"))){ 

 echo "'.$r2[invoiceid].'";

 }
```

si ven en la query hay otra variable que seria el resultado de la primera query ....

la primera query arroja una serie de campos de 1 tabla ....

como podria lograr esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una subconsulta y así te ahorras el tener que hacer la doble consulta, siempre que no necesites ningún otro dato de la primera. La consulta sería asi:

```
SELECT * FROM tblinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceid in(SELECT valor de invoiceid FROM tblaccounts WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-12-25 0:00:00' AND '2016-07-20 23:59:00')
```

Otra forma de hacerlo, sería recorriendo los resultados de la primera consulta y generar la segunda consulta, tal y como planteas

```
<? 
$db_link=conectarse();
$consulta="SELECT * FROM tblaccounts WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-12-25 0:00:00' AND '2016-07-20 23:59:00'";
$sql=mysql_query($consulta, $db_link);
$num_reg = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($num_reg!=0){
   while ($mostrar = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
          $consulta2="SELECT * FROM tblinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceid = =$mostrar[id]";
          $sql2=mysql_query($consulta2, $db_link);
          $num_reg = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
          if ($num_reg!=0){
             while ($equipos = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 
             }
          }
          mysql_free_result($sql);
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias, lo resolvi integrando la consulta a la principal con inner y join ... digamos que relacionando tablas asi:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblaccounts inner join tblinvoiceitems on tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid=tblaccounts.invoiceid WHERE tblaccounts.date BETWEEN '$_POST[date1] 0:00:00' AND '$_POST[date2] 23:59:00'");
```